# Getting content length is not supported in Yii EAjaxUpload

Tags: file-upload, yii

I am using Yii EAjaxUpload extension to upload files. I am facing a problem during uploading image. 'Getting content length is not supported'. In console It is showing the error "**http://46.101.98.121/MyApp/index.php?r=controller/upload&PHPSESSID=j7…KEN=077cb06478a3c70e40a2a01dc4cb1a94a6ff96ec&qqfile=518164-backgrounds.jpg**". In php.ini 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size' both are 100MB. File is already uploaded to the destination folder but the uploading procedure fails each time. Please help.

Comment: Check if upload folder is set with sufficient permissions and then check if server sends `$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]`.

Comment: Thank you Bizley. I have already solved this problem. Server CONTENT_LENGTH was returning 0 . So I faced the problem.

Comment: @Rachita, could you please let me know how you fixed it?